# Quelles différences entre « agacer », « embêter » et « déranger » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Les trois verbes ci-dessus ont la même définition : je veux savoir s'il y a une différence entre le sens des mots.

Par exemple, dans la phrase suivante, puis-je remplacer «agacer» par l'un des deux autres ? Est-ce que ce changement changerait le sens de la phrase ?

> Ce qui m'agace c'est quand mon frère ne se mêle pas de ses oignons.

Comment: This is much like the verbs 'to annoy', 'to bother' and 'to disturb' in English - largely the same, but I'd say it's unlikely one would use 'déranger' in this context.

Comment: @AnupamaG c'est ce que je pensais, mais je voulais le confirmer. Aussi, écrire des questions en français est pour moi la bonne practique

Comment: Vous avez bien raison.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Embêter** est assez léger, et indique un problème ponctuel.

On peut demander à quelqu'un: *Est-ce que je peux t'embêter ? (te poser un problème, une question, te demander quelque chose)*

**Ennuyer** peut être synonyme, en ce qu'il implique un problème, ou différent, si cela provoque un ennui (sens que n'a pas embêter).

**Agacer** souligne une répétition et aboutit à être énervé, las.

**Exaspérer** est le stade ultime, où *on n'en peut plus*.

**Ulcérer**, assez identique à exaspérer.

**Outrer**, qui peut aussi indiquer un énervement immédiat.

Il y a aussi quelques verbes grossiers qui ont ces sens: **casser les pieds**, ...

**Déranger**: plus neutre, et avec un sens plus précis, et concernant une action en cours: *quelqu'un dérange*, quand il intervient alors qu'on est en train de faire quelque chose. Il n'y a pas de connotation forcément négative.

On peut demander à quelqu'un: *Est-ce que je peux te déranger ?*

On peut aussi dire **distraire**, qui est plus léger.

Un emploi figuré de *déranger* a un sens négatif: *un comportement, une réflexion qui dérange*: qui crée un problème, un malaise, ou qui est à contre-courant.

Comment: Donc, déranger et embêter a presque la même utilisation (poser une question, &c.) et agacer/ennuyer sont plus négatifs ?

Comment: @BenKnoble oui, exactement

Comment: Bon merci de votre réponse vite.

Comment: @BenKnoble - réponse rapide (adjectif) - répondre vite (adverbe). de rien

Comment: Zut. Comme j'ai déjà dit, ce site est bon pour pratiquer. Merci.

Comment: *Ulcérer*, renvoie à *ulcère*, crispation gastrique qui noue le ventre et met en colère ; *outrer* à *outrage*, offense faite à la réputation, à l'ego.