# Gêner et déranger : quel est leur usage correct ?

Tags: sens, usage

Français:

Je trouve souvent dans les textes des expressions comme « ça me gêne » ou « ça me dérange », mais je n'ai jamais su distinguer leur sens correctement... Pour moi, ils me semblent interchangeables. Est-que j'ai raison ?

English:

I often found in some texts some expressions like 'ça me gêne' or 'ça me dérange', but I've never been able to distinguish their meaning correctly... To me, they seem interchangeable. Am I right?

P.S: Please free to correct my french. Thanks

Comment: Note de correction: En français, seule une idée peut être "correcte", on ne dira jamais qu'une personne est "correcte" dans ce sens là. On préfère dire qu'une personne a raison (positif), qu'elle se trompe (négatif), ou qu'elle a tort (négatif)...

Comment: Le sens de déranger est précisé [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/18170/7321). Il y a beaucoup de synonymes, mais "gêner" n'en fait malheureusement pas parti, on est passé à coté :) [ces définitions](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/g%C3%AAner/36509) de "gêner" sont intéressantes aussi

Comment: @Random merci pour la correction (?) ;)

Comment: @Random Au votre dernier link, avec les plusieurs définitions de "gêner", le premier exemple est: «Déranger quelqu'un dans son corps, dans sa liberté de mouvement, lui procurer une sensation de gêne physique : Le col de ma chemise me gêne, il est trop étroit.» En fait, les troisièmes premiers exemples ont un mot dérivé de "déranger"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les sens de ces deux verbes se recoupent seulement partiellement :

[déranger](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9ranger) dans son sens B.2.a ("Troubler dans ses occupations, gêner") veut bien dire [gêner](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/g%C3%AAner) ("Causer une gêne physique ou matérielle à quelqu'un") dans son sens A.2.

Ils sont donc interchangeables dans ce cas. Un exemple d'interchangeabilité est quand quand l'inconfort est modéré et physique :

> Le soleil dans les yeux me gêne pour travailler

ou

> Le soleil dans les yeux me dérange pour travailler

Un cas où ils ne sont pas interchangeables :

Déplacer ce qui était rangé :

> Il a dérangé mon bureau. <==> Il a mis mon bureau en désordre.

Dans le sens général, « ça me gêne » sera plus utilisé quand le dérangement est d'ordre éthique :

> Ne m'offre pas le repas, ça me gêne

ou pudique :

> Je ne me mets pas en maillot de bain, ça me gêne

alors que déranger sera utilisé quand une activité est interrompue :

> Ne me téléphone pas au bureau, ça me dérange

Comment: Alors, est-ce que je peux déduire de votre réponse que le mot 'déranger' a un sens plus physique, tandis que le mot 'gêner' est plus psychologique?

Comment: la "gêne" peut être liée à l'idée de honte, donc dans une certaine mesure, oui.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Pas forcément. « La voiture mal garée gène le passage des bus » = physique , « Cette attitude me dérange » = psychologique.

Answer (score 1):

Les deux mots sont pareils, mais je dirais que "gêner" es un peu plus informel.

Comment: Non les deux mots ne sont pas toujours « pareils » (on dirait « ont le même sens ») et ça n'a rien à voir avec une question de niveau de langue.